# Setting struts2 checkbox based on boolean bean attribute

Tags: java, checkbox, struts2, javabeans

I have a struts2 checkbox as follows:

```
 <s:checkbox id="frequencyBased" name="tramBean.frequencyBased" value="false" onclick="changeFrequency()"/>
```

I have a bean with the following methods:

```
public void setFrequencyBased(boolean isFrequencyBased) {
     this.isFrequencyBased = isFrequencyBased;
}

public boolean isFrequencyBased() {
     return isFrequencyBased;
}
```

When I check the box and submit the form, the boolean is set appropriately (checked -> true, unchecked -> false).

When I return to the page, however, with the attribute set, the checkbox does not update to reflect the setting.  I have a breakpoint in isFrequencyBased(), and I can tell it's not being called.  What am I doing wrong; how do I get the checkbox to read the attribute in the bean?

Comment: You set the value explicitly; not sure what you expect.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I thought that the ' value="" ' attribute was for the base value, which is overridden when there's a value present in the bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<s:checkbox id="frequencyBased" name="tramBean.frequencyBased" value="tramBean.frequencyBased" fieldValue="true" onclick="changeFrequency()"/>
```